# Clarity Wizard - Jump to page X on open (clrWizardOpenChange)

Tags: vmware-clarity, clarity

I've created a wizard with three pages.
When the wizard opens, I want to directy navigate to page two and not start one page one.

I tried to use the clrWizardOpenChange Event on my wizard, but `this.wizard.pages` seems to be undefined or no pages are initialized at this moment.

Is there some way to achieve this behaviour?

[Stackblitz](https://clarity-light-theme-v11-7mej9b.stackblitz.io)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're opening the wizard in the `ngOnInit()` of your own component. At that point none of the views or the pages exist, your app is pretty much still bootstraping.

If I use a button to open the wizard and just group the "skip to second page" and the "open" in the same callback, it works fine: https://stackblitz.com/edit/open-wizard-page?file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: This seems to work when the wizard is called in the same component where the method is used. I want the wizard to be initialized through a service that creates the component via a ComponentFactory so the wizard is a component by itself.

Also a little sidenote `#setCurrentPage()` is deprecated, `#makeCurrent()` should be used instead.